# Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member when calling assembly from NAV

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-storage, dynamics-nav

I'm developing a library to upload files to Azure-Storage, to be called from Dynamics NAV ERP. If I call the library method that uploads the file from a Test Console, it works. If I call it from the ERP I get the error:

> Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member:
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException.GetObjectData.

I've read other similar topics. The method is marked as SecurityCritical. I works from my test console. From the ERP, it does not. Any clue? Thanks in advance.